# Using a sp with an out variable get the following error message: Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a stored procedure in MySql that contains an out variable but when I want to call it, I get the below error. Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?
Here is the sp:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storedp2`(out shift nvarchar(40))
begin
set shift= (SELECT * FROM myblog.computed);
end
```

and here is how I call it:

```
set @test='';
call storedp2 (@test) ;
select @test as t;
```

and here is error:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return single value:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storedp2`(out shift nvarchar(40))
begin
set shift= (SELECT col_name FROM myblog.computed WHERE id = ?);
-- (single column/single row)
-- set shift = (SELECT col_name FROM myblog.computed WHERE ... LIMIT 1);
end;
```

You cannot assign result of `SELECT * FROM tab` to `NVARCHAR(40)`:

```
scalar :=  (col1, col2, col3)         -- won't work (multiple cols, single row)
scalar :=  (col1, col2), (col1, col2) -- won't work (multiple cols, multiple rows)
sclara :=  (col1), (col1)             -- won't work (single col, multiple rows)
```

**EDIT:**

> *what should I do if I want to return the whole select sentance*

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storedp2`()
begin
  -- some logic
  SELECT * FROM myblog.computed;
end

call storedp2 ();
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d570b25c4141e68fb15f5aa4c8440a67)**

Comment: Thanks. what should I do if I want to return the whole select sentance. @Lukasz Szozda